# TextMate ToolTip Fonts

Tags: tooltip, textmate

i'm new to textmate. 
for the "complie&run" job for the java bundle, i set the output: "Show in tooltip" format "text". Everything works exactly as it should. The problem is the tooltip font is not proportional to the font of the text. for ex, doing a "Command+" or "Command-" doesn't proportionately change the font-size of the tooltip.

i also tried `$defaults write -g NSToolTipsFontSize 24.0` which does a good job for chrome/safari browser apps (tooltip gets larger) but not for mate.

To know exactly what i mean here's the dropbox link: [TextMate ToolTip Image](http://tinyurl.com/o5mz3yh)

i am using textmate2, lion 10.7 on a macbookpro.
thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Mavericks and needed that as well but could not get NSToolTipsFontSize to work; upon requesting the support staff at to help, they have added the support for that in their edge build.

Now I can use

`$defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview NSToolTipsFontSize 24`

I checked it and it works for me.  Please see their response below:-

> We’ve added support for this value now, it is available in the current edge build. Go into  Preferences and do to the Software Update tab and **hold option while clicking check now**, you will get **r9569** with this added.
>
> (Note that this won’t cover popups created via TMDialog but only those created as output from bundle items, but this will cover 95%+ of the cases.)

Comment: thank you for the comment. really needed in TMDialog. don't have enough reputation to upvote! maybe later i'll mark as "correct"

Answer (score 3):

com.macromates.TextMate.**preview** did not work for me on Mac OS 10.13 with TextMate 2.0 RC 10... Below default command rather worked

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate NSToolTipsFontSize 24
```

Comment: I did send out a note to Macromates to validate this and here is the response... "Yeah sorry we removed the .preview extension last year once we were not seeing people dual-running TextMate 1.x and 2.0. That is the correct command now. We have a guide about that here:""

https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS 13.4.1 with TextMate 2.0.23. Thanks!

com.macromates.TextMate.preview didn't work for me as well.